Find iPhone with location services turned off
The battery of my iPhone SE 1st generation started to die and Apple no longer carries new batteries for that model.  I immediately replaced it with a 3rd generation.  Due to its much greater expense, I started to explore the capability of finding a lost iPhone.  The iPhone is the only Apple device that I own.
If I turn on location services on the iPhone, I can use any browser to log into iCloud and locate the iPhone.
When location services is turned off (on the iPhone), the location doesn't show up on the browser.  I usually turn off location services.  Is there any way to remotely turn it on from iCloud?
I note that if I don't have my iPhone, I cannot fulfill the 2-factor authentication needed by iCloud and my sign-in to iCloud is limited to finding the iPhone.
I found similar questions about enable "location" or "Find My" on a stolen phone, but I'm specifically interested in enabling location services on a stolen phone.
Furthermore, the responses to those similar questions refer to an information page for when the phone is stolen, but it does not say whether location services can be turned on remotely.
I have seen mention of the capability to use a network of Apple devices to locate a stolen/lost phone that is turned off, but haven't been able to find much detail about it.

You can't enable Location Services remotely. With LS disabled, you can't track the phone continuously, but if you set Lost Mode on icloud.com, you may still get intermittent updates from other Apple devices that happen to be nearby:

The Find My network is an encrypted, anonymous network of hundreds of millions of Apple devices that can help find your stuff, even when it's offline. Nearby devices securely send the location of your missing device to iCloud, so that you can find it in Find My.

If Find My shows "No location found" or "Offline" (support.apple.com)
Although I can't find any official documentation, according to at least one user report LS will be enabled temporarily to send a "last location" fix if the phone is in Lost Mode and it connects to a Wi-Fi network. To be certain, you'd have to test this yourself.
Does send last location work with location services off? (apple.stackexchange.com)

Thank you, Linc Davis.  I was afraid to try Lost Mode because I didn't know whether it would lock up my device (and I hadn't had a weekend with which to carefully parse the information that I found online).  It looks like exploring Lost Mode is something to read up on more carefully and to explore on a weekend (when I have more time).

You may want to think about whether it's a good idea to keep Location Services disabled. Your concerns about it might be a topic for another question, if you can't find an answer by searching the site. It doesn't enable Apple to track you, and you can be tracked anyway by cellular providers (and by authorities, with a court order.)

I will definitely look into this. Thanks!

I did an internet search and most forum postings cite advantages of enabling location services, but using less data and battery to having less info for apps to take. Since the user has control over what apps can access location services, I think my reasons would be restricted to data and battery. I have to weigh this against the ability locate my phone, taking into consideration the likelihood of it being stolen.  I suspect that Apple and Google can track me regardless of whether I enable location services, and my carrier definitely can.
